# Extract Substring from String Python

Tags: python, regex, substring, function

I'm trying to extract the following substring from the string

```
-- CVS Header: $Source: /CVS/oracle11i/database/erp/apps/pkgspec/wwt_prime_pkg.p
ls,v $, $Revision: 1.14 $, $Author: $, $Date: 2014/09/23 21:41:15 $
```

String I want to extract: `$Revision: 1.14 (or just 1.14)`

My code is as follows:

```
from sys import *
from os.path import *
import re 

script, filename = argv

print "Filename: %s\n" % filename

def check_string():
    found = False
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
        if re.search("(?<=\$Revision: ) 1.14", line):
            print line
            found = True
        if not found:
            print "No Header exists in %s" % filename

check_string()
```

This does not seem to be working.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What does *"This does not seem to be working"* **mean**, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly in and split should do what you want :

```
if "$Revision:" in line:
    print(line.split("$Revision: ")[1].split()[0])
1.14


In [6]: line ="""
   ...: -- CVS Header: $Source: /CVS/oracle11i/database/erp/apps/pkgspec/wwt_prime_pkg.p
   ...: ls,v $, $Revision: 1.14 $, $Author: $, $Date: 2014/09/23 21:41:15 $
   ...: """

In [7]: line.split("$Revision: ")  # split the line at $Revision: 
Out[7]: 
['\n-- CVS Header: $Source: /CVS/oracle11i/database/erp/apps/pkgspec/wwt_prime_pkg.p\nls,v $, ',
 '1.14 $, $Author: $, $Date: 2014/09/23 21:41:15 $\n']

# we use indexing to get the first element after $Revision:  in the string
In [8]: line.split("$Revision: ")[1] 
# which becomes the substring below
Out[8]: '1.14 $, $Author: $, $Date: 2014/09/23 21:41:15 $\n'

# if we call split again we split that substring on whitespace into individual strings
In [10]: '1.14 $, $Author: $, $Date: 2014/09/23 21:41:15 $\n'.split()
Out[10]: ['1.14', '$,', '$Author:', '$,', '$Date:', '2014/09/23', '21:41:15', '$']

# using indexing again we extract the first element which is the  revision number
In [11]: '1.14 $, $Author: $, $Date: 2014/09/23 21:41:15 $\n'.split()[0]
Out[11]: '1.14'
```

It is the same for `$Date`:

```
 date  = line.split("$Date: ")[1].split()[0]
```

Or just use `in` if you just want to check for a substring in the string:

```
if "$Revision: 1.14" in line:
    print line
```

Comment: No worries, you're welcome. I was not fully if you wanted to check for membership or extract the revision number but the code will do both

Comment: Can you please explain what the [1].split()[0] is doing? Also, what if I wanted to extract the date in $Date: 2014/09/23 21:41:15? I realize the same syntax would work fine, but is there a way to not have to do another if ""$Date" in line"?

Comment: are $Date and $Revision always together?

Comment: They'll always need to be extracted, yes.

Comment: are they always in the same line, I mean, if $Revision is in the line does it mean $Date will also and vice versa?

Comment: then no prob `date = line.split("$Date: ")[1].split()[0]` if one is both are so only need to check for one

Comment: So if I wanted to print the date and time would this be the best way (since they are separated by a space)?

Comment: date = (line.split("$Date: ")[1].split()[0])
time = (line.split("$Date: ")[1].split()[1])

Comment: yes exactly, they return `'2014/09/23'` and `'21:41:15'` respectively from your input example
`
`

Answer (score 2):

```
if re.search("(?<=\$Revision: ) 1.14", line):
```

your line won't work because you try to match two spaces between `:` and `1.14`, try:

```
if re.search("(?<=\$Revision: )1.14", line):
```

or

```
if re.search("\$Revision:\s+1.14", line):
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex requires two spaces between the colon and the version number, and the input only contains one.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> string="""-- CVS Header: $Source: /CVS/oracle11i/database/erp/apps/pkgspec/wwt_prime_pkg.p
... ls,v $, $Revision: 1.14 $, $Author: $, $Date: 2014/09/23 21:41:15 $"""
>>> re.findall(r'\$Revision:\s*([0-9.]*)',string,re.DOTALL) # if more than one such value is to be searched
['1.14']   
>>> re.search(r'\$Revision:\s*([0-9.]*)',string,re.DOTALL).group(1) # if only one such value neeeds to be found 
'1.14'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

def check_string(f,target):
    for line in f:
        if line.find(target)>=0:
            return line

script, filename = argv

f = open(filename)
rev_line = check_string(f,'Revision: 1.14')
if rev_line:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

#### The `check_string` function

1. No need for regexp
2. `line.find(target)` returns `-1` on failure, index of `target` in `line` on success
3. if the index is no less than `0` we have a match, so we return `line`
4. if we don't find a match, we fall out the border of the function, returning `None`

#### The calling program

After the usual boilerplate we assign to the variable `rev_line` what is returned by `check_string`.  If we have not found `'Revision: 1.14'`, `rev_line` is `None`, otherwise is the full line containing the target. Go on to do what is to be done in both cases.

#### Edit

If *the revision number is not known at the time of writing the program*, you have two cases

1. *the revision number* is sourced from a file, or otherwise computed, and *is know at time of execution*

   ```
   target = 'Revision: %d.%d' % (major, minor)
   rev_line = check_string(f, target)
   ```
2. *the revision number is not fully known at the time of checking*, in this case you build a `target` string containing a regexp and modify the innards of `check_string`, in place of the  `if line.find(target)>=0:` you write `if re.search(target, line):` that is very similar to what you've written in the 1st place, BUT the regexp is no more hardcoded into the function and you're free to determine it in the main program body.

All in all, `2.` is better, because you can always build a "constant" regexp...

Comment: I like this logic here, but one thing I forgot to mention..the 1.14 will not always be that value. It could be 1.x (x being any value).