# String formatting need a solution

Tags: python, string

How do I format this string:

```
'Item:       Intel NUC onboard PC\n'
```

so I get this output:

```
Intel NUC onboard PC
```

thanks

Comment: I dont agree that this is a duplicate of [Extract Substring from String Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823034/extract-substring-from-string-python)

Comment: please be helpfull for newcomers

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
'Item:       Intel NUC onboard PC\n'.split(':')[1].strip()
>> 'Intel NUC onboard PC'
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach might be to `partition` on the `:` and then `strip` the result:

```
>>> print(s.partition(':')[2].strip())
Intel NUC onboard PC
```

Note that this assumes that you won't have a `:` in the `Item` part of the string (i.e. the leftmost `:` will be the partition point, so any remaining `:`s will be in the final string, not in the part that got chopped off).